# Resources res = mPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication("com.packagename"); is not working 6.0 and below

Tags: android

ResourceNotFound exception in 6.0 and below..am trying to access drawable from another application. In my ccase i would like to apply theme from another application. For example launcher app.

### Method:1

```
    try {

                String mDrawableName = "icon";

                Resources mApk1Resources = manager.getResourcesForApplication(package_name);
                int mDrawableResID = mApk1Resources.getIdentifier("icon", "drawable", package_name);
                Drawable myDrawable = mApk1Resources.getDrawable(mDrawableResID);

                if (myDrawable != null) {
                    data.add(new DataModel("" + app_name, myDrawable, package_name));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

### Method:2

```
            try
            {
                Context otherAppContext = getActivity().createPackageContext(""+package_name, Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE | Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
                Resources mApk1Resources = otherAppContext.getResources();
                int mDrawableResID = mApk1Resources.getIdentifier(package_name+":drawable/icon", "drawable", package_name);
                Drawable myDrawable = mApk1Resources.getDrawable(mDrawableResID);

                if (myDrawable != null) {
                 data.add(new DataModel("" + app_name, myDrawable, package_name));

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Are you assuming that every app has a drawable resource named `icon`? Or do you know for certain that the app you're trying to access has that particular drawable?

Comment: both applications are mine only.. so not assuming i know clearly the drawable name and its working fine 7.0 + versions

Comment: In which folder is `icon` located in the target app? That is, do you happen to have it only in `res/drawable-v24/`, or similar? Does `icon` work correctly in the app itself on 6.0?

Comment: yes got solution.. thank you very much @MikeM. icon was misplaced in second application.